# How do I Deploy a ClickOnce application to Customer site as part of Install?

Tags: deployment, installation, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce app which ties into our software and we deploy and use internally. We want to get this to customers, but with the customer hosting the clickonce update site. As far as I can see from [The Instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx), I have to sign the deployment manifest after creating it, and to create it I need to know the update site.

I don't know the update site until Install Time (on the customer site), but I don't want our certificate to be on the customer sites.

How can I deploy the application in this way? or am I misunderstanding how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Walkthrough: Manually Deploying a ClickOnce Application that Does Not Require Re-Signing and that Preserves Branding Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384246.aspx) looks like it closely matches my scenario.

Comment: I glad to see ClickOnce moving this direction. We have a .net 2.0 ClickOnce client we distribute and I had some MSI custom actions written to automate the resigning at install. Never liked having to do that.